# How to detect endianess to keep a consistent byte order with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, endianness

I am having an issue with iOS byte orders. We are sending messages over BLE, some of the values are stored as NSInteger objects

I have an older (but still supported) iPad appears to store integers with big-endian byte order which is required for our peripheral to correctly interpret the value, however when I run the same application on a newer iPhone it doesn't work and the endianness is reversed.

```
NSInteger number = 230; /* this is actually declared elsewhere, this is just for the example */

short value = (short)number;

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)&value length:sizeof(value)];

int intData = [self intFromNSData:data];
```

Result values coming through are

```
On iPad: 230 (00E6)
On iPhone: 58880 (E600)
```

As you can see the byte order is different on the two devices, I just want to know how I can detect and, if necessary, swap the bytes before I send them to the peripheral device. Or is there a different way to store these numbers that will be consistent across all devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to detect the endianness of the device running your app. To ensure that you always send the bytes as big-endian, use the appropriate `NSSwapHostXXXToBig` function.

```
short value = 230;
short beValue = NSSwapHostShortToBig(value);
NSData *data = ...
```

Or you can use the `CFSwapXXXHostToBig` functions. These work well with the various fixed size data types such as `uint16_t`.

```
uint16_t value = 230;
uint16_t beValue = CGSwapInt16HostToBig(value);
NSData *data = ...
```

Each of these have corresponding functions to convert the big-endian value back to a proper host value if needed.

Comment: I thing this is a typo instead of `CG` prefix should be `CF` in second example. I can't edit it since must be at least 6 characters changed.